# SQL Server 2008 SP1 takes a long time to restore database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 SP1. It takes a long time when restoring the database from backup file. Following the Microsoft support website (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975089) that was a bug of SQL Server 2005 & 2008 and they released a update package which named "Cumulative update package 5 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1". I installed the update package but nothing happened. SQL Server is restoring the database until now and I can not stop restoring process.

Does anybody give me any advices?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction to enable trace flag 4133?

Comment: Not programming related --> belongs on Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Thank Ed Harper for your useful advice. I run the following statement to Enable trace flag 4133:

```
DBCC TRACEON (4133, -1);
```

Pay special attetion to "-1" parameter to make type of flag is globalization.